# How do i make it when a user presses a button the phone vibrates?

Tags: java, android

Any tutorials for this? Code? Instructions would be great! :) thanks! I have an android phone btw and im using it to help me test the code. Im new to Java. Thank you

Comment: What have you done and tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vibrate the phone you have to request permissions to access in the manifest.
Give uses-Permission to the following

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

after that in the button click event

```
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);//Initiate the vibrate service
vib.vibrate(100);
```

you have to code like the above.

Answer (score 0):

First learn how to handle button clicks
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Then, in order to vibrate the phone you have to request permissions to access in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Then in the function which can handle the button click event , you can decide how to vibrate the phone

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html